# TypeScript - returning type of child object in parent class? (Typings of singleton)

Tags: typescript

I have following problem.
In typescript I made abstract class for singleton, but I'm looking for a correct typings of response.

```
abstract class Singleton {
    private static _instance: any;
    static get instance(): any {
        if (!this._instance) {
            var me: any = this;
            this._instance = new me();
        }

        return this._instance;
    }
}

class Test extends Singleton {
    public test(): string {
        return "hello world";
    }
}

var testInstance = Test.instance;
// then testInstance dont support intellisence of supported methods
```

actually I used "any", but when I call instance, it logically didnt show any methods / props of child. 
I'm looking for possibility to write somethink like "Children" instead of "any" - is some definition like that in TypeScript possible?

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You could use generics. Since you can't use generics on properties `get instance()` becomes `getInstance()`.

```js
abstract class Singleton {
    private static _instance: any;

    static getInstance<T>(): T{
        if (!this._instance) {
            var me: any = this;
            this._instance = new me();
        }

        return this._instance as T;
    }
}

class Test extends Singleton {
    public test(): string {
        return "hello world";
    }
}

var testInstance = Test.getInstance<Test>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Ryan answer from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41813537/how-do-i-create-an-abstract-factory-pattern-in-typescript). You can follow pattern he introduced and write something like this

```js
abstract class Singleton<T> {
    private _instance: T 
    constructor(private modelConstructor: new () => T) { }

    public create(): T {
        if (!this._instance) {
            return new (this.modelConstructor)();  // OK!
        }
        return this._instance
    }
}

class Test {
    public test(): string {
        return "hello world";
    }
}

class TestFactory extends Singleton<Test> {
    constructor() {
        super(Test);
    }
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=abstract%20class%20Singleton%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_instance%3A%20T%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20modelConstructor%3A%20new%20()%20%3D%3E%20T)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20create()%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(!this._instance)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20(this.modelConstructor)()%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20OK!%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this._instance%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20test()%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22hello%20world%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20TestFactory%20extends%20Singleton%3CTest%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(Test)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20const%20TestFactoryInstance%20%3D%20new%20TestFactory()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0ATestFactoryInstance.create()%0D%0A%0D%0A).